# Xamarin Forms Triggers in cs file

Tags: xamarin.forms

I try to implement a trigger for my control in c# file. When my property IsChecked is true, it should change the Source of Image to CheckedImageSource. I have implemented the trigger exactly like in [git repository](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/WorkingWithTriggers/WorkingWithTriggers/csharp-examples/SimpleTriggerPage.cs) of msdn example, but my trigger doesn't change the image source.

```
public class CustomCheckbox : CachedImage
{
    public CustomCheckbox()
    {
        GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer { Command = TapCommand });

        var binding = new Binding { Source = this, Path = nameof(UncheckedImageSource) };
        SetBinding(SourceProperty, binding);

        var trigger = new Trigger(typeof(CustomCheckbox))
        {
            Property = IsCheckedProperty,
            Value = true,
        };
        trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter
        {
            Property = SourceProperty,
            Value = CheckedImageSource,
        });
        Triggers.Add(trigger);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsCheckedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(IsChecked),
        returnType: typeof(bool),
        declaringType: typeof(CustomCheckbox),
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CheckedImageSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(CheckedImageSource),
        returnType: typeof(ImageSource),
        declaringType: typeof(CustomCheckbox));

    [TypeConverter(typeof(ImageSourceConverter))]
    public ImageSource CheckedImageSource
    {
        get => (ImageSource)GetValue(CheckedImageSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(CheckedImageSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty UncheckedImageSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(UncheckedImageSource),
        returnType: typeof(ImageSource),
        declaringType: typeof(CustomCheckbox));

    [TypeConverter(typeof(ImageSourceConverter))]
    public ImageSource UncheckedImageSource
    {
        get => (ImageSource)GetValue(UncheckedImageSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(UncheckedImageSourceProperty, value);
    }

    private ICommand _TapCommand;
    public ICommand TapCommand => _TapCommand ??= new Command(OnTapCommand);

    private void OnTapCommand()
    {
        IsChecked = !IsChecked;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use OnPropertyChanged because it is a simple dimple.

Answer (score 0):

Try to your constructor method like below:

```
   public CustomCheckbox()
    {

        GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer { Command = TapCommand });
        var trigger1 = new Trigger(typeof(CustomCheckbox))
        {
            Property = IsCheckedProperty,
            Value = false,
        };
        trigger1.Setters.Add(new Setter
        {
            Property = SourceProperty,
            Value =  "your uncheck image.png"
        });

        this.Triggers.Add(trigger1);

        var trigger2 = new Trigger(typeof(CustomCheckbox))
        {
            Property = IsCheckedProperty,
            Value = true,
        };
        trigger2.Setters.Add(new Setter
        {
            Property = SourceProperty,
            Value = "your check image.png"
        });

        this.Triggers.Add(trigger2);
        var binding = new Binding { Source = this, Path = nameof(UncheckedImageSource) };
        SetBinding(SourceProperty, binding);
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately, this still doesn't work :(

Comment: Did you use the direct image name (xxx.png) instead of the `CheckedImageSource` and `UncheckedImageSource` ?